# Populate Dynamic Values for Json Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am new to json schema and I am having a hard time looking for a solution to my problem.
I need to populate the data sent by the server to json editor using the schema shown below.

Note: this is just a snippet of the schema.
I have a json schema that looks like this:

```
 


    {
      "id": "#ProcessApplicationList",
      "type": "array",
      "title":"ProcessApplicationList",
      "description":"List of process application.",
      "items": {
        "id": "#ProcessApplication",
        "type": "object",
        "required":[
        "ProcessId",
        "InputParameter"
        ],
        "title":"ProcessApplication",
        "description":"Process application.",
        "properties": {
          "ProcessId":{
            "id":"#ProcessId",
            "type":"string",
            "title":"Identification code of process",
            "description":"e.g. 'process#01'"
          },
          "InputParameter": {
            "id": "#InputParameter",
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {
              "anyOf": [
                { "type": "string" },
                { "type": "number" },
                { "type": "boolean"}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This is the sample response from the server.

```
 

    {
      "Acceptability" : {
        "ProcessList" : [
          {
            "ProcessId" : "process#01",
            "ProcessName" : "sign",
            "ProcessDescription":"sign your plug-in by using signature",
            "ProcessAvailability" : true,
            "ProcessParameterSchema" : {
              "\"$schema\":\"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\",
              \"sign_type\":{
                \"id\":\"#sign_type\",
                \"type\":\"string\",
                \"title\":\"sign_type\"}
            },
            {
              "ProcessId" : "process#02",
              "ProcessName" : "encryption",
              "ProcessDescription":"encrypt your plug-in by using key",
              "ProcessAvailability" : true,
              "ProcessParameterSchema" : {
                "\"$schema\":\"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\",
                \"enc_type\": {
                  \"id\":\"#enc_type\",
                  \"type\":\"string\",
                  \"title\":\"enc_type\"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

the output of the JSON editor should be something like this:
![IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/2r61r0k.png

I need to put the value of "ProcessParameterSchema" to "InputParameter".
I need to update "InputParameter" for every element in "ProcessApplicationList".
Since "ProcessApplicationList" is an array, I am not sure how to do the update.
thank you!

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more your intention. Json-schema just allows you validate json against schema. Do you want to adapt the response in order to get the schema validation? Are you doing hot-changes in schema from response and then use the resulting schema to validate?

Comment: @jruizaranguren: I updated my question for more info. Yes, i want to update my json schema everytime i receive a new response, i need to update the "InputParameter" for every element in "ProcessApplicationList" so that schema from "ProcessParameterSchema" will be shown in JSON editor. Thank you.

Comment: Can you retrieve all possible "ProcessParameterSchema" in advance?

Comment: i will get the value of "ProcessParameterSchema" first before i will create the json schema for validation. My problem is that i do not know how to put the value of "ProcessParameter" to "InputParameter" since it can be different for every element in "ProcessApplicationList"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be applied to your specific situation, but the general solution would be the use of [json hyper-schema](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-hypermedia.html).

With json hyper-schema you can define the API available operations, using "schema" property for defining the acceptable request formats. The schema of the answer can be linked through "href" links, so the client could process dinamically each possible schema.

A second option, if you have every possible nested-schema in client side, would be to express that through a "oneOf" property that holds a collection of "href"s. In that case you could use those href's to take proper decissions to validate and draw UI. An interesting variation of this would be to resolve the href's to backend valid URI's (which is a way to hack the HAL approach described first).

Comment: hi! thanks for the reply. i actually have read about this one but i got confused about how to do it. i am trying to look for a similar case or reference code so that i can have a headstart.